# TypeError: tokenize_lemmatize_spacy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'first_arg'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror, tfidfvectorizer, countvectorizer

So I am  getting this error trying to return different value of my sklearn vectorizer :

```
>>>  python features.py lemmatize_PS Gold.xlsx
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "features.py", line 351, in <module>
    fea1, fea0, fe, fi, fo, fu, fo, fea2 = build_feature_matrix_S(sentences)
  File "features.py", line 100, in build_feature_matrix_S
    vectorizer_freq = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = tokenize_lemmatize_spacy(first_arg), binary=False, min_df=5, ngram_range=gram)
TypeError: tokenize_lemmatize_spacy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'first_arg'
```

the tokenize_lemmatize function is like this :

```
def tokenize_lemmatize_spacy(texte, first_arg):
    texte = normalize(texte)
    mytokens = nlp(texte)

    if first_arg == 'lemmatize_only':
        # Lemmatizing each token and converting each token into lowercase
        mytokens = [word.lemma_.lower().strip() for word in mytokens if word.pos_ != "SPACE"]

    elif first_arg == 'lemmatize_PS':
        # Lemmatizing each token and converting each token into lowercase
        mytokens = [word.lemma_.lower().strip() for word in mytokens if word.pos_ != "SPACE" ]
        # Removing stop words and punctuations
        mytokens = [word for word in mytokens if word not in stopwords and word not in punctuations]

    else:
        raise Exception("Wrong feature type entered. Possible values:  'lemmatize_only', 'lemmatize_PS'")
    return mytokens
```

I tested the function token_lemmatize and it works but now when I am trying to use it in another script I get the error below.

Answer (score 0):

`CountVectorizer` expects a callable but you are trying to feed the output of the function.

use `partial`

```
from functools import partial
vectorizer_freq = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=partial(tokenize_lemmatize_spacy,
                                                    first_arg='lemmatize_PS')
                                  binary=False, min_df=5, ngram_range=gram)
```